# Presentation of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

For some calculation I need the precise elements of each order order. I have seen that ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ is group of order $24$ having elements: $1$ of order $1$ and $2$,  $8$ elements of order $3$, $6$ elements of order $4$ and $8$ elements of order $4$.

> It is known that ${\rm SL}(2,3)=\langle x,y,z:x^3=y^3=z^2=xyz \rangle$. How can we see the elements $x,y$ and $z$ in terms of matrices.

I have seen some where that $$ A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$ B=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
will generate the group ${\rm SL}(2,3)$. I wants to know how we can the presentation like above. Please help me I tried a lot but not succeeded.

Comment: See the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724627/the-generators-of-sl-2-bf-f-3) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396068/structure-subgroup-of-sl2-3). You can choose $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $1$ and coefficients $0,1,2$. Then you can test what subgroup they generate. For $x,y,z$ see [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/SL(2,3).html).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you sir.