# Presentation of SL$(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I know a presentation of the special linear group SL$(2,3)$([Presentation of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401352/presentation-of-rm-sl2-3)). My question is that-

> Can we give a presentation for SL$(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ in general or in more general can we  give a presentation for SL$(n,\mathbb{F})$,where $\mathbb{F}$ is field.

As J.P. Serre had given presentation for SL$(2,\mathbb{Z})$

$$\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \langle \,S, T \mid S^4 = 1, (ST)^3 = S^2 \,\rangle$$
where,
\begin{align}
    S &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \phantom{-}0& 1 \\ -1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix},
    &
    T &= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
I wants it to be more general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry sir, now I have edited it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde actually sir, I have to do some calculation over SL$(n,\mathbb{F})$, thats why I need this.

Comment: For a group $G$ there are typically many presentations of $G$, so you mean "I know a presentation of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$", not "I know the presentation of ${\rm SL}(2,3)$". The English word "the" implies uniqueness. There are indeed of presentations of ${\rm SL}(n,F)$ for fields $F$ in the literature (Steinberg presentations for example), and there are a number of other specific presentations of ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ for finite fields. I think this question is really too broad and you should perhaps ask something more limited.

Comment: For $SL(n,p)$ see the article "Presentations of finite simple groups" by Guralnik et al., section $6.1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are presentations of $SL_n(K)$ for a field $K$, in particular for $K=\Bbb F_p$ and also for $SL_n(\Bbb Z)$. In the latter case we obtain this from the theory of arithmetic groups. The result is listed for $n\ge 3$, for example, in $5.6$, page 14 of the article [An introduction to arithmetic groups](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=2ahUKEwjAtaH6m_vlAhVMSsAKHdzYDDwQFjAFegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhal.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Fhal-00001348%2Fdocument&usg=AOvVaw0fyZvEnCh4nF4JVMuBg56j) by Christophe Soule: 
denote by $x_{ij}$ the matrices with diagonal elements $1$ and another entry $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and zero entries otherwise. Then we have
$$
SL_n(\Bbb Z)=\langle x_{ij}, 1\le i\neq j\le n\mid [x_{ij},x_{kl}]=1 \text{ for } j\neq k, i\neq l,\; [x_{ij},x_{jk}]=x_{ik} \text{ for }i,j,k \text{ distinct }, (x_{12}x_{21}^{-1}x_{12})^4=1 \rangle
$$
We can also generate the group by two elements only, but the relations then become very long. For the references see [6,9,20] in Soule's lecture notes.

Comment: Sir can you give some reference for $SL(n,\mathbb{Z}_p)?$

Comment: Yes, the article by Guralnik, see above, section $6.1$.