# generators of $SL(2, \mathbb{F}_3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I am interested in finding all the relations between two matrices in $SL(2, \mathbb{F}_3)$. Namely, these matrices are $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ I tried and it looks painful to me. I am not sure at which moment I have to stop. What is the best way to do that? Is it possible to do it in SAGE? My strategy was to just write down all the words in these two matrices and see what happens but I don't this it's a good idea.

Comment: Denote these matrices by $A$ and $B$. Since $A^3=I$, it is enough to compute $A^2$. Since $B^4=I$, compute $B^2$ and $B^3$. Now look at products between $A,A^2$ and $B,B^2,B^3$. The group has $24$ elements. By the way, generators are also given at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724627/the-generators-of-sl-2-bf-f-3).

Comment: @DietrichBurde but I'm interested in these particular generators. Also, they don't explain all the relations between those two generators that you linked so I'm not sure how it helps. It makes sense that it's enough to consider only small powers but I'm not sure how to bound from above the number of relations.

Comment: Taking an isomorphism from the presentation given at the other posts, mapping your generators to the others, or vice versa,  it is clear that there will not be many relations. You can take the standard presentation [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/SL(2,3).html). It has only $6$ relations.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This link is useful, thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde But it seems to me it contains a mistake. Namely, those matrices that they give as generators at bottom do not satisfy cac^(-1)=b.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Never mind, I figured it out, thanks!